# How to stop a transparent-fill circle getting mouse events inside it?

Tags: javafx, mouse, shapes, fill, stroke

I want a `Circle` to respond to mouse events only when the mouse is on it's 'stroke' , i mean boundary. Of course, the circle has a transparent fill and a colorful stroke. Extending `JavaFX Path` looks painful to me, is there any way to do that with this `Circle` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution does not work anymore in Java 9 but in your case you could just set the fill of the circle to null. This should have the same effect.

Comment: Wow! I knew there is a much better idea. How cool is that! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution doesn't work with Java 9:**
Ok, finally I found an excellent way to do that. It may help others in the future:

`javafx.scene.shape.Shape` class has a Deprecated method

`boolean impl_computeContains(double localX, double localY)`

which invokes another method  `computeShapeContains(localX, localY, impl_configShape())`

Now, scene graph decides whether a point is in a shape or not by

`boolean contains(double localX, double localY)` method from JavaFX.scene.Node which invokes that impl_computeContains method. So I had a look at those method and overrode the impl_computeContains mthod like this:

```
@Override
    protected boolean impl_computeContains(double localX, double localY) {
        float miterlimit =
            (float) Utils.clampMin(getStrokeMiterLimit(), 1.0f);
        return Toolkit.getToolkit().strokeContains(impl_configShape(), localX, localY, getStrokeType(), 
                Utils.clampMin(getStrokeWidth(), 0.0f), getStrokeLineCap(), getStrokeLineJoin(), miterlimit);
    }
```

and boom!! it works!! All I did was, I removed the part which implemented what to do if the point was on the shape's interior part.